# How to 'Logging' without adding a line to every method

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# web api project, basically I need to log everytime a method is getting called (ie. method name, parameters passed, result, stacktrace (if error occured), etc).

Right now, I did this by adding few lines to every method and it seems bloated, is there more efficient way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can use middleware.

Comment: Are those methods only action methods (methods defined into the controller) ?

Comment: Do you really want to log every method or just when an error / specific action takes place?

Comment: @LeisenChang: Any recommendation?

Comment: @CodeNotFound: Yes, only action methods inside every controler

Comment: @sr28: Every method

Comment: You could use something like the decorator pattern to make it easier. Good example of this with logging is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/february/aspect-oriented-programming-aspect-oriented-programming-with-the-realproxy-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware is one approach, or you can also create a Filter that lets you perform 'before' and 'after' operations,

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-filters

[Code from the above link]

```
public class LogDemoAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public LogDemoAttribute()
    {

    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Action Method {0} executing at {1}", actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()), "Web API Logs");

        var result = await continuation();
            
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Action Method {0} executed at {1}", actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()), "Web API Logs");

        return result;
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

This does let you add to the Global Filters (in which case, you might as well use a Middleware), or add it selectively to certain endpoints, e.g

```
[ApiController]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase 
{ 
    [LogDemo]
    [HttpGet("demo/endpoint")] 
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that you might want to pass in some parameters to the attribute, that let you perform certain context specific behaviours.

If you want to add logging to non-controller code, then you can take this approach further to an Aspect Orientated / Decorator pattern.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/february/aspect-oriented-programming-aspect-oriented-programming-with-the-realproxy-class

I generally find logging parameters at the controller level is good enough, and something like Application Insights that generates telemetry that shows you what the request looks like is actually the useful bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

When you're saying "method" I'm unsure if you mean literally every method or just whenever a controller is being hit. But middleware would probably be the way to go. The documentation on adding custom middleware is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1
And here is an example of error handling middleware, where you could place your logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1